# Swift: Saving Multiple Images to Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a Recipe entity with a one-to-many relationship to RecipeImage. The problem I'm having is how to properly save multiple images. What I'm trying to do is once I selected the images, I store them in a tempImageArray. Once I select "Done" I try to convert images within tempImageArray into an array of data since Core Data only accept images as Binary Data. I then set my recipe.images as that array of data.

Currently, I'm only able to save 1 photo instead multiple.

I think im close to the solution but just needs some guidance. Any help you be much appreciated!

```
class ListDetailViewController: UITableViewController {

var recipeToEdit: Recipe?
var recipeImages = [RecipeImage]()

//image collection
var tempImageArray = [UIImage]()

 private func createRecipe() {
    let context = CoreDataManager.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext
    
    let recipe = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Recipe", into: context) as! Recipe
    recipe.setValue(textField.text, forKey: "name")
    
    let image = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "RecipeImage", into: context) as! RecipeImage

    for i in tempImageArray {
        image.imageData = i.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8)
        recipeImages.append(image)
    }
    
    recipe.images?.setValue(recipeImages, forKey: "images")
    image.recipe = recipe
   
    do {
        try context.save()
        
        //Perform save
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        self.delegate?.didAddRecipe(recipe: recipe)
        
    } catch let saveErr {
        print("Failed to save recipe", saveErr)
    }
}
```

Comment: You are updating the `imageData` of the same image inside the loop. Try creating a new entity for each image by moving `let image = NSEntityDescription...` inside the loop.

Comment: When I do that, I lose access to "image.recipe = recipe". When I put that in the loop, I get an error.

Comment: If you have relationship b/w image and recipe, you don't have to set both `recipe.images` and `image.recipe`. Create `to many` relationship from `recipe` to `image` and `to one` relationship from `image` to `recipe` and regenerate the model classes.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem! all I had to do was removed the recipe.images.setValue